# Python input is read right to left?

Tags: python-2.7, input

I want to make a phonebook dictionary with name/number

I enter the following code but it seems the input is read from right to left

```
p = {} 
p[raw_input()] = raw_input() 
print p
```

e.g. if I enter:

sami
123

the following dictionary is created:

```
{'123': 'sami'}
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: The `=` assignement is evaluated form right to left, not how the input is read. Otherwise it would be something like `{'321', 'imas'}`.

Comment: You'd find this a lot less confusing if: 1. You gave a useful prompt message; and 2. You didn't take two inputs on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right-hand side of the assignment operator is evaluated first, then the expression in the left-hand side is evaluated to choose where to store the value.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

Here, the "expression list" is the right-hand side, whereas the "target list" is the left-hand side. (Since assignments like `a, b = 1, 2` are valid in Python.) It's easier just to think of this as "expression" and the "target" in this case.

Following these rules, if I start with:

`p[raw_input()] = raw_input()`

I start by evaluating the "expression list" (the right-hand side, `raw_input()`, at which point the user enters 'sami'), at which point I effectively have:

`p[raw_input()] =`**`'sami'`**

The left-hand side (the "target list") is a [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions); the [docs tell us](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt):

> If the target is a subscription: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated. It should yield either a mutable sequence object (such as a list) or a mapping object (such as a dictionary). Next, the subscript expression is evaluated.

So, I start by evaluating the "primary expression" in the reference (which is just `p`):

**`p`**`[raw_input()] =`**`'sami'`**

And then evaluate the "subscript expression" (`raw_input()` again, user types 123):

**`p`**`[`**`'123'`**`] =`**`'sami'`**

Now the assignment can be completed, resulting in the dictionary containing `{ '123': 'sami' }`